# How to send chunk size to particular processes with MPI_Scatterv?

Tags: c, mpi

With use of

```
MPI_Scatterv(sendbuf[], sendcounts[], displs[], sendtype, recvbuf[], recvcount, recvtype, root, comm)
```

two arrays are used to handle variable length of chunk sizes of data to be sent to particular processes: sendcounts and displs. The first one is the number of elements to send to each process and displs is start index of sendbuf from which sendcounts is counted - but receive buffer has same length for each process. In such situation how can I tell each process how many elements of its recbuf[] should it read to process? I.e. Process 0 will get 1 element, Process 1 will get 3 elements, but both of them have recbuf[] with 4 elements in length.

Comment: `sendcounts` and `sdispls` are only relevant in the root rank. `recvcount` is specific to the local rank (read all ranks do not have to use the same value). So you should have each rank receive the same amount of data the root rank will send to itself.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet sure, but how can I tell each rank how many elements it should read from its recbuf[]? I.e. recbuf[] has length of 4 elements, but rank=2 will get only 2 values in there, how can I send information to rank=2 that it has to read only first two elements out of all 4?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution I found is just to initialize sendcounts[] array for EACH rank. It will be some waste of memory when same data will be generated as many times as ranks are involved but in this way all of them will have same data and all will know exactly how many elements to read from their particular recbuf's. Below is sample of implementaion according to this approach. Please take a look and correct me if I made it wrong in any way - all comments are welcome.

EDIT2:

@GillesGouaillardet based on your second answer (about f()) I have modified the code again, now each rank gets its recbuf length based on function output - now recbuf array is not used beside root rank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define DISPLACEMENT_SIZE 4

int getsendcount(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int rank, size;

        MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

        int *rcvbuf = malloc(getsendcount(rank) * sizeof(int));

        // root node will initialize input array of data and displacements when only root needs them for Scatter
        if(!rank)
        {
                int *intab, *sendcounts, *displs;
                int displacement = 0;
                displs = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
                sendcounts = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
                int f = 0, mainindex = 0;
                intab = malloc(size * DISPLACEMENT_SIZE * sizeof(int));

                // every rank will get its own chunk of data, but all will get SAME copy
                for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
                {
                        *(sendcounts + i) = getsendcount(i);
                }

                // generating input data array
                for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
                {
                        for(int j=0; j < DISPLACEMENT_SIZE; j++)
                        {
                                *(intab+mainindex) = 1*f;
                                mainindex++;
                        }
                        f += 10;
                }

                // initializing displacements array, every DISPLACEMENT_SIZE fields for each rank
                for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
                {
                        *(displs + i) = displacement;
                        displacement += DISPLACEMENT_SIZE;
                }

                // debug block to see values
                for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
                {
                        printf("displs[%i] = %i, sendcounts[%i] = %i\n", i, *(displs+i), i, sendcounts[i]);
                }
                putchar('\n');

                for(int i=0; i < mainindex; i++)
                {
                        printf("%i ", *(intab + i));
                }
                putchar('\n');

                MPI_Scatterv(intab, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT,rcvbuf, getsendcount(rank), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else
        {
                MPI_Scatterv(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ,rcvbuf, getsendcount(rank), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        printf("this is proces %i, got: sendcounts %i\n", rank, getsendcount(rank));

        for(int i=0; i < getsendcount(rank); i++)
        {
                printf("Process %i my %i buffer value is %i\n ", rank, i, *(rcvbuf + i));
        }
        MPI_Finalize();

        return 0;

        }

int getsendcount(int i)
{
        return i - (i/DISPLACEMENT_SIZE * DISPLACEMENT_SIZE) + 1;
}
```

Comment: The receive count has to be `sendcounts[rank]` instead of `BUF_SIZE`. Also, you might not want to print more data than received. That being said, you can directly compute this value on non zero ranks without initializing and populating the `sendcounts` array, and that will be more efficient. In the general case, only the root rank has the information to compute `sendcounts`, so an option (which is the least efficient one) is to `MPI_Scatter(sendcounts, 1, MPI_INT, &receivecount, 1, MPI_INT, ...)` before `MPI_Scatterv()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, agree that in such situation I can use sendcounts[rank] to optimize memory usage and set recbuf in apropriate lengths - in the code by use of fixed length just wanted to show more clearly how it behaves in such configuration with different recvbuf lengths.
Could you clarify what do you mean by 'you can directly compute this value on non zero ranks without initializing and populating the sendcounts array, and that will be more efficient'?

Comment: It is **not** correct to receive more data than sent in collective operations (point to point are fine). Currently, `sendcounts[i]` depends on `sendcounts[i-1]` but it really  depends on `i ` so you can revamp this.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, could you clarify what do you mean by 'you can directly compute this value on non zero ranks without initializing and populating the sendcounts array, and that will be more efficient'?

Comment: Yes I could, and I did too (`sendcounts[i] = f(i)`). Writing the `f()` function is left as an exercise, I do not want to spoil the fun.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, but the approach with use of function that calculates recbuf for each rank is suitable only in situation when those valuse can be calculated in somehow. In case when I have fixed values of lengths for each rank then I will have to create sendcounts array copy for each rank? Please review the last change of the code where I have added function that you wrote about in your previous comment.

Comment: The most general case is that `sendcounts` can only be computed on the root rank, and you have to `MPI_Scatter()` it before you can `MPI_Scatterv()`. As a matter of style, you might want to use the array notation (e.g. `sendcounts[i]`) instead of dereferencing a pointer (and relying on pointer arithmetic, e.g. `*(sendcounts + i)`).